# How to round numbers when performing linear interpolation?

Tags: statistics, interpolation, rounding-error

Say I have to find the number of people above a certain mass. I can do linear interpolation to get a value that will give me the number of people below this mass and I can simply subtract this from the total number of people to get my answer.
However, I'm a little confused regarding decimal numbers. If 23.8 people out of 31 are below 63 kg, how do I get logically (rounded) accurate values for the number of people below and above 63 kg?

Comment: It may be that I don't fully understand the question. What is wrong with this: Without rounding: 23.8 people out of 31 are below 63 kg and 7.2 out of 31 are above 63kg. With rounding : 24 people out of 31 are below 63 kg and 7 out of 31 are above 63kg

Comment: Hmm. I guess. I was just thinking about why would would round up instead of down. Eehh. It's okay. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you do not want non-integers here (although I cannot see any reason why because it is only a proportion) , you can say $119$ out of $155$ which is the same proportion described with integers.

Comment: @Evargalo It might be because that one only works when you split in two (unless you happen to split exactly on the $0.5$ mark). As soon as you split in at least three, you can divide $31$ in three numbers all of which must be rounded down (say, $10.4$, $10.2$ and $10.4$, the roundings of which sum to $30$).